# openpyxl iter_rows only loops through the first cell

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop, openpyxl

I am trying to compare 3 column of data in 2 separate worksheets and if the data match then copy the info on other cells over. The below code works and gets me the result I want but it only runs the first cell in A_Rows. I want it to loop through the length of A_Rows and pass in the second row of A_Rows

```
A_Rows = A_List.iter_rows(min_row=2,min_col=5,max_row=289,max_col=7)
B_Rows = B_List.iter_rows(min_row=2,min_col=5,max_row=48927,max_col=7)

for name,dob,gen in A_Rows:
    for name2,dob2,gen2 in B_Rows:
        d1 = dob.value.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        d2 = dob2.value.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        if str(d1)==str(d2):
            if gen.value==gen2.value:
                if name.value in name2.value.upper():
                    A_List.cell(row = name.row, column=4, value=B_List.cell(row=dob2.row, column=4).value)
                    A_List.cell(row = name.row, column=8, value=B_List.cell(row=dob2.row, column=8).value)
                    A_List.cell(row = name.row, column=9, value=B_List.cell(row=dob2.row, column=9).value)
                    A_List.cell(row = name.row, column=11, value=B_List.cell(row=dob2.row, column=11).value)
```

Comment: To loop over two sets of rows in parallel use `zip()`, the ranges look odd for doing this. And if you're looping over row ranges, you don't need to perform additional cell lookups.  Also, compare dates directly rather than as formatted strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initialising B_Rows once before the processing so it cylces once only. For this to work you'd need to move that iter_rows line to be inside the loop.

```
A_Rows = A_List.iter_rows(min_row=2,min_col=5,max_row=289,max_col=7)
# Move this into the loop
# B_Rows = B_List.iter_rows(min_row=2,min_col=5,max_row=48927,max_col=7)

for name,dob,gen in A_Rows:
    # for name2,dob2,gen2 in B_Rows: <--- is not initiated again after first loop of Row_A
    for name2,dob2,gen2 in B_List.iter_rows(min_row=2,min_col=5,max_row=48927,max_col=7)
        d1 = dob.value.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        d2 = dob2.value.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        if str(d1)==str(d2):
            if gen.value==gen2.value:
                if name.value in name2.value.upper():
                    A_List.cell(row = name.row, column=4, value=B_List.cell(row=dob2.row, column=4).value)
                    A_List.cell(row = name.row, column=8, value=B_List.cell(row=dob2.row, column=8).value)
                    A_List.cell(row = name.row, column=9, value=B_List.cell(row=dob2.row, column=9).value)
                    A_List.cell(row = name.row, column=11, value=B_List.cell(row=dob2.row, column=11).value)
```

Comment: The explanation isn't correct and moving B_Rows inside A_Rows will make it iterate once for each row in A_Rows